# Is there a way to have a Windows Service delay a PC shutdown until an action has completed?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-services

I've developed a PHP/MySQL e-commerce website for a small business that is hosted externally.

An exact replica of the same database is also hosted onsite at the businesses physical store to be accessed via there point of sale application (which I've also developed in C#.NET).

I now have to develop a way of keeping the two databases synchronized.

I am thinking of writing a Windows Service (in C#.NET) which compares the two databases every 5 minutes (when the PC on which the Windows Service is running is actually turned on), however I have a question regarding Windows Services.

If I were to shutdown the PC on which the Windows Service was running while a database synch was taking place - is there a way to make the PC wait until the synch has completed before shutting down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if a service can use it but [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) purpose is about warning a user that an operation is pending while a shutdown is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AbortSystemShutdown or shutdown /a but it works only on scheduled shutdown.

If you want to use serice to do that you can use

```
protected override void OnShutdown() 
{
    base.RequestAdditionalTime(max_time_of_your_db_sync_in_ms);
    serviceCore.OnShutdown();
    Stop(); 
}
```

refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Msdn says that RequestAdditionalTime method 'overridden OnContinue, OnPause, OnStart, or OnStop'..

you can not override RequestAdditionalTime method on OnShutDown